# <br>how to install nagios check_procs plugin in nagios</br>

Tags: linux, ubuntu, plugins, nagios

I am new to nagios and I have installed nagios 3 on my linux machine.

i want to install nagios check_procs plugin.can any one suggest me.thanks

Comment: Please elaborate on the description, provide a proper question, describe what you have already tried and where is the problem. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You can install from package which depends on Linux distribution you use.
If it is rpm based then install "nagios-plugins" package.

## rpm -qf  /usr/lib64/nagios/plugins/check_procs

nagios-plugins-1.4.15-2.el6.rf.x86_64

Answer (score 0):

From the tags you've marked on your question, I assume you are using ubuntu as Operative System to your Nagios' Server,

First of all try to verify where is your resources file

```
# find /* -name resource.cfg
```

The answer should be something like '/usr/local/nagios/etc/resource.cfg'

Then find where are your plugins, pointed in the resources by the $USER1$ variable (the code below assumes your resources.cfg is in /usr/local/nagios/etc/

```
# grep '\$USER1\$' /usr/local/nagios/etc/resource.cfg
```

You'll get the folder of your scripts (in my case it is /usr/local/nagios/libexec/):

```
$USER1$=/usr/local/nagios/libexec
```

If in that folder you do not find a check_procs, than you'll need to install a newer version of nagios plugins:
 - you can either run the command bellow

```
apt-get install nagios-plugins
```

Otherwise you can go to the official Nagios' site and download/install the plugins package: http://www.nagios.org/download/plugins, inside the nagios-plugins .tar.gz archive there is a README file with good instructions for the manual installation process